# Empty /var/log after running cron bash script

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I wrote a little bash script and all of a sudden my /var/log folder is completely empty except for the log I created for the bash script.

This is the script I'm running every hour with cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
STL_DIR=/path/to/some/folder/i/hid
LOGFILE=/var/log/stl_upload.log

now=`date`
echo "----------Start of Transmission----------" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE
echo "Starting transfer at $now" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

rsync -av -e ssh $STL_DIR exo-l@rsync.hidrive.strato.com:/users/path/folder 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE

echo "----------End of transmission----------" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE
printf "\n" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

I want to be clear that I'm not 100% certain this is related to the empty logs folder. So if anyone could give me a pointer as to what could be going on about the reason why my log folder is empty, that'd be great.

Comment: There's no reason why this would have affected any files other than `/var/log/stl_upload.log`. There's something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is still unknown what happened, but a server reboot regenerated the log files again (had to touch a couple manually). Still very strange issue, but as we are moving to a new environment (managed by a 3rd party) this week, this question is considered answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, your logrotate or syslog.conf config might be archiving logs to a different directory? And it was all just coincidence?  Can't think of any other reason.  (I realize this question is answered, I'm just curious too)